# How to roll the 'R' when it is followed by an 'L'

Tags: pronunciación

So far rolling the **R** (in words like hacer, abrir, perro, pero) works quite well for me. But I have a problem when the **R** is followed by the letter **L**, like in **hacerlo**. It works a bit better when I widen my mouth and say the word very slowly, but maybe you have any other hints for me. Where to put my tongue, how to open my mouth. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The words that have an 'r' behind any consonant sound kind of strong, similar to the double 'r' like in the word "perro". You could try pronouncing first the verb "hacer" and then pronounce "lo". After that you slightly decrease the space between the pronunciation of them.

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Agreed. The best way is first sepparating all syllabes, then increasing speed. Words to practice: Carlos, perla, chirla, Merlos, orla, estraperlo,...

Comment: It's all about having a strong tongue. Once you can roll the Rs without forcing it, you will be able to do it at any point in a word. It's just a matter of practice. Try saying "recorrerlo alrededor" over and over, or the good old tongue twister: "Erre con erre cigarro, erre con erre barril, rápido ruedan los carros por los rieles del ferrocarril".